# linearlayout centered vertically between two linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, vertical-alignment

I need to do a layout like the one in the picture, using 3 linearlayout, or relativelayout or whatever similar. The linearlayout in the middle has to adapt the height depending on the free space between the first ll one the top and the third ll at the bottom.
The ll at the bottom has to be fixed there.
[image]

How can I do?

Thanks, Mattia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The important thing here is the `android:layout_weight="1"`  in the second layout

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ui_main_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>


    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ui_main_footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ui_main_center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_below="@id/ui_main_header"
        android:layout_above="@id/ui_main_footer"

        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```